# Google map disappear when modal class is active

Tags: javascript, c#, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I have this modal:

```
<form id="contactModal">
<div id="mymodal2" class="" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">                  
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <span class="modal-title th2" id="lblModalLabel" name="lblModalLabel">Contact</span>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
```

If I don´t add `class="modal"` like

```
<div id="mymodal2" class="fade modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

I don´t have any problems with map, the problem 
is when I try to add modal class my map disappear, why it happens?

---Update---

If I run application without modal class like:

```
<div id="mymodal" class="" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
```

and then open google chrome inspector and add class through it. It loads map into modal.

Here is my JS code:

```
 try {
            map = new GMaps({
                div: '#gmap_marker',
                lat: 19.4368277,
                lng: -99.1905598
            });


            map.addMarker({
                lat: 19.4368277,
                lng: -99.1905598,
                title: New City",
                infoWindow: {
                    content: '<strong>City</strong>'
                }
            });
            console.log("gmap processed");
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }

    $("#btnFirstMap").click(function () {


        try {
            map = new GMaps({
                div: '#gmap_marker',
                lat: 19.4368277,
                lng: -99.1905598
            });


            map.addMarker({
                lat: 19.4368277,
                lng: -99.1905598,
                title: "FirstMap",
                infoWindow: {
                    content: '<strong>City2</strong>'
                }
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }

    });

    $("#btnCity3").click(function () {


        try {
            map = new GMaps({
                div: '#gmap_marker',
                lat: 18.6490907,
                lng: -91.8218911
            });


            map.addMarker({
                lat: 18.6490907,
                lng: -91.8218911,
                title: "City3,
                infoWindow: {
                    content: '<strong>City3</strong>'
                }
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }

    });
```

Comment: The default state of a modal is hidden (I believe). If you have the class as `modal`, you would still have to show the modal after the page loads.

`$('#myModal').modal('show');`

Comment: I add   $('#contactModal').modal('show'); before validate and it no works

Comment: `contactModal` appears to be a `form` as per your original code. If the map is actually inside `mymodal` or `mymodal2`, and they have their class set to `modal`, these are the divs that need .modal('show')` called.

Comment: Yes I see, but `mymodal` only runs on load page, but I need to load script when page loads

Comment: You can wrap any of the JavaScript you have into functions and then call them how you wish. There is `window.onload`, or the `body` tag accepts `onload=someFunction()` as well. There are many ways to run JavaScript when the page is loading.

Comment: Try calling `setTimeout(function(){ google.maps.event.trigger(map.map,'resize'); }, 500);` AFTER the modal is shown, e.g. after you call `...modal('show');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to:

1) explicitly set map container size, for example via CSS:

```
div#map {
    width: 560px !important;
    height: 600px !important;
}
```

2) Reload the map once the modal dialog is shown via `resize` event:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var map = createMap();
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); 
    });
})
```

**Example**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var map = createMap();
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); 
        });
    })

});


function createMap() {
    var mapControl = new GMaps({
        div: '#map',
        lat: -12.043333,
        lng: -77.028333
    });
    mapControl.addMarker({
        lat: -12.043333,
        lng: -77.03,
        title: 'Lima',
        details: {
            database_id: 42,
            author: 'HPNeo'
        },
        click: function(e) {
            if (console.log)
                console.log(e);
            alert('You clicked in this marker');
        }
    });
    return mapControl.map;
}
```

```css
div#map {
    width: 560px !important;
    height: 600px !important;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/gmaps.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


 
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="modalOne" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Show map</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>

                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Map</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/QEKpNK)